# Programmatic export/dump/mass data retrieval (BaaS)

Tags: rest, export, parse-platform, paas, stackmob

Does anyone have experiences with *programmatic* exports of data in conjunction with BaaS providers like e.g. parse.com or StackMob?

I am aware that both providers (as far as I can tell from the marketing talk) offer a REST API which will allow for queries against the database, not only to be used by mobile clients but also by e.g. custom web apps.

I am also aware that both providers offer a manual export of data (parse.com via their web interface, StackMob via support).

But lets say I would like to dump all data nightly, so that I can import it into a reporting system for instance. Or maybe simply to have an up-to-date backup.
In this case, I would need a programmatic way to export/replicate the data stored in the backend. Manual exports are not an option for obvious reasons.
The REST APIs offered however seem to be designed for specific queries, not for mass reads (performance?). Let alone the pricing - I assume none of the providers would be happy about a nightly X Gigabyte data export via their REST API, so their probably will be a price tag.

I just couldn't find any specific information on this topic so far, so I was wondering if anyone else has already gone through this. Also, any suggestions on StackMob/parse alternatives are welcome, especially if related to the data export topic.

Cheers, Alex

Comment: Looks like I'm about to earn another Tumbleweed badge...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you see the section of the [Parse REST API on Batch operations](https://www.parse.com/docs/rest#objects-batch)?  Batch operations reduce the number of API calls needed to grab data so that you are not using a call for every row you retrieve.  Keep in mind that there is still a limit (the default is 100, but you can set it to a maximum of 1000).  That means you are still limited to pulling down 1000 rows per API call.

I can't comment on StackMob because I haven't used it.  At my present job, we are using Parse and we wrote a C# app which compares the data in a Parse class with a SQL table and pulls down any changes.